# Loader for images that are in another page that are gathered with ajax, in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, loader

*Edit:* Here is the new code:

```
        $("#normalcontent").hide("fast").load($this.attr("href") +" #normalcontent","",function(){
        $(this).slideDown("normal");
        $(this).find("img").each(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("large"))
            {
                var myThis=$(this);
                myThis.css("display","none");
                var img = new Image();
                $(img).attr("src", "images/ajax-loader.gif");
                $(img).css({
                    border:"none",
                    width:"16px",
                    height:"11px"
                });
                myThis.after(img);
                myThis.load(function(){
                    $(img).remove();
                    myThis.fadeIn("normal");
                })
                .error(function(){
                    $(img).attr("src","images/errorIcon.png").css({
                        border:"none",
                        width:"14px",
                        height:"14px"
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

> Hello.
>
> Let's say I have a link in "index.php", when I click on that link, it loads, via ajax, a content from a page "content.php" into a div element in "index.php", that has an id of "#content". That content in "content.php" has large images. I want to display an image loader,  say "ajax-loader.gif", instead of those large images, until the images are downloaded by client.
>
> ( I know how to have an image loader .gif for the images on "index.php". )
>
> How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#blah').load('/index.php #content', function () {
    $(this).find('img').each(function () {
        var self = $(this),
            replacee = $('<img src="/ajax-loader.gif/>');

        this.onload = function () {
            replacee.replaceWith(self);
        };

        self.replaceWith(replacee);
    });
});
```

I'd be careful about your layout though... I doubt swopping large images for small loaders is ideal. As a user, I'd prefer to delay the showing of the whole content, until all images have loaded.

Comment: hmm, but what if the situation is an image gallery?
changing only the src attribute,instead of changing whole <img ... />, would do right?

Comment: @abdullah: Yes, but you'll still have to create a new image, and set it's `src` to the `src` of the gallery image, and detect `onload`, so the gallery image continues to load. You should also be wary of any `height`/`width` attributes that would mess up the `ajax-loader`.

Comment: Will it be OK, if I hide the large image, add my loader gif after it, and when the large image finishes loading, show it, and remove loader gif?